# Alter column which is a composite key-Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to alter Version column to decimal(3,1) but it is giving this error

> The object 'PK__SlideVer__E0872D0E86F75C91' is dependent on column 'Version'.

fkSlideId is a foreign key.See the image

[image]

Comment: Drop Primary Key and alter that column. Then recreate it.

Comment: I have tried to drop primary key: Alter Table Drop Primary Key (col1,col2) but it does'nt work

Comment: What error you got? same like previous?

Comment: Its a syntax error.

Comment: Syntax for dropping constraint is "Alter table Table_name drop constraint constraint_name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just shown you a sample example.

```
CREATE TABLE TAR1
    (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    )



        ALTER TABLE TAR1 ADD CONSTRAINT PK_1 PRIMARY KEY(ID,NAME)

        ALTER TABLE TAR1 ALTER COLUMN NAME VARCHAR(50) -- will throw an error

        ALTER TABLE TAR1 DROP CONSTRAINT PK_1

        ALTER TABLE TAR1 ALTER COLUMN NAME VARCHAR(50)  not null --You must specify not null
        ALTER TABLE TAR1 ADD CONSTRAINT PK_1 PRIMARY KEY(ID,NAME)
```

Comment: I can't create a new table need to update the current one

Comment: I did'nt make constraint when created this table

Comment: @SyedKamranAhmed For that drop existed Primary key then alter column with your required datatype and must specify not null. After above steps you need to create Pk again. For more understanding, can u post your Primary keys, Foreign Keys in detail?

Comment: @SyedKamranAhmed Follow syntax which i have mentioned in my post for dropping constraint or You can also follow vicky .

Answer (score 0):

As @Buddi pointed, you need to first drop the primary key and other any dependent object before altering your column.

```
ALTER TABLE SlideVersion
DROP CONSTRAINT PK__SlideVer__E0872D0E86F75C91
```